# Automation script(s) to run website X hours and then turn monitor on/off managed with crontab not working

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cron

I'm setting up a office computer to show X website from 6AM to 6PM and then turn off the monitor (Samsung TV) at 6PM and on again at 6AM by using crontab and bash scripts for the job.
Executing the scripts works fine both from the command line and from crontab but after a few hours of running the website the monitor goes to sleep.

This might be to me being a novice on linux and scripting but any help would be appreciated.

I'm running ubuntu 18.04 turned off "Dim screen when inactive", "Blank screen", "Automatic suspend" and "Screen lock" in settings>privacy/power

I've tested the scripts functionality with 5 minutes intervals in crontab and it works fine but when I run it for several hours it fails.

Script for showing the website

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
export DISPLAY=:0.0
firefox -height 1080 -width 1920 google.com &
win=$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --class firefox | head -1)

while [ "$win" == "" ]; do
        win=$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --class firefox | head -1)
        sleep 0.1
done

sleep 10

xdotool key --window=${win} F11
sleep 5
xdotool key Page_Down

sleep 12h
killall firefox
exit 0
```

Script for turning the screen on

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
export DISPLAY=:0.0
xset dpms force on
```

Script for turning the screen off

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
export DISPLAY=:0.0
sleep 1; xset dpms force off

0 6 * * 1-5 /bin/bash /home/acte/startDisplay.sh
1 6 * * 1-5 /bin/bash /home/acte/hallScript.sh
2 18 * * 1-5 /bin/bash /home/acte/stopDisplay.sh
```

Crontab file

```
0 6 * * 1-5 /bin/bash /home/acte/startDisplay.sh
1 6 * * 1-5 /bin/bash /home/acte/hallScript.sh
2 18 * * 1-5 /bin/bash /home/acte/stopDisplay.sh
```

So from the crontab file I expect the computer to turn the monitor on at 6AM and then at 6:01AM run my script to visit the website, show that website until 6:01PM when the script exit and then turn the monitor off at 6:02 PM - rinse & repeat

Comment: I read somewhere that I could throw in a suffix to specify the time.. https://linuxhint.com/sleep_command_linux/ there for example

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sleep.1.html says in the manual I should be able to add suffix aswell